# Android app to access Visual Studio Online

Tags: android, visual-studio

I would like to see my [Visual Studio Online](http://www.visualstudioonline.com/) (in particular my backlog, PBIs and tasks) on my Android phone.

Do you know if there is an app that include this feature?

Answer (score 1):

[Work Item Studio](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.workitemstudio), developed by **Microsoft**, does that.

> Work Item Studio, a Microsoft Garage project, allows you to view,
>   create and edit work items from your projects on Visual Studio Online.
>
> You can also see a list of all your queries, along with the number of
>   results in each of them. Quickly run your queries to see detailed
>   results.

Here are some screenshots from its Google Play space:

[image: Work Item Studio - My Work]
[image: Work Item Studio - My Queries]
[image: Work Item Studio - Product Backlog]

Alternatively, I'd suggest you to try browsing your Visual Studio Online account with the **browser** on your device. If the website follows good principles of responsive design, you might be able to do all you need directly from there.

Comment: Thanks @mguassa for this app. Android playstore tell me that this app is not available in my country (France) :(

Comment: @boly38 It's a shame it doesn't work there. In practice, at the moment, it seems the only decent app that does what you asked for and it's rated with at least 3 stars. Anyway, I've just edited my answer adding an alternative to it, give it a go.

Comment: Thanks @mguassa I will try UI responsiveness of VSO.

Comment: @boly38 You're welcome. Let me know if it works decently for you and I could add a new dedicated answer for it.

Comment: VSO website seems don't have a mobile version.

Comment: "this app is not available in my country" - could you use a proxy? Just for installation

Answer (score 0):

VSO applications/clients:

- [TFS Client for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.homegrownsoftware.AndroidTFS)  - 2/5 stars
- [Work Item Studio](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.workitemstudio) - 3/5 stars - N/A in France